# 'read_image' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)

Tags: javascript

```
$(el).append(`
<input type="file" onchange="read_image(this)">
`);

function read_image(input){}
```

I get this error: `'read_image' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)`

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with:

```
$(el).append(`
<input type="file" onchange="read_image(this)">
<script>
function read_image(input){}
</script>
`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the "read_image" function is declared but never used TypeScript is throwing that error. You have it inside of a dynamic element that may not or may exist.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19700

Comment: I don't know about typescript, I just changed the file type to module so that I can import/export. If I put this logic into a regular js file, it works. But that's not why I am using modules...

Comment: Typescript has weird rules to help ensure your code is following certain benchmarks. The error is thrown because the read_image method is not explicitly called; rather it is called dynamically and the Typescript linter does not notice it. You can look up comment methods to ignore the issue or switch to JavaScript because JS does not care about things like that.

Comment: I understand what the problem is but what can I do about it? I tried to call the function right after I define it, but still no success.